# Inaccessable files under orignal default username

Tags: files, default, username

Downloaded all old files from hard drive to new ubuntu computer.  I did not change the user-name from the default OEM user-name, but changed it after.  All my folders are no longer accessible, how do I retrieve them?

Comment: You have to log in as the root user which can be done by going into the terminal and typing `sudo -i` and then type your root password.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a directory called `transfer-dir` with all of your transfered files in it and your new user's name is `penguinfan`. 
 You would run the following to change the ownership of the files to your new user:
`sudo chown -R penguinfan: transfer-dir`

#### sudo

- is needed to be able to change ownership of another user's files

#### chown

- changes ownership of files

#### -R

- changes ownership recursively

#### penguinfan:

- This is short for `penguinfan:penguinfan`, which changes the user and group of files.

#### transferdir

- tells chown to use change ownership of/in the `transferdir` directory.